# BigQuery: Set expirationTime on a destinationTable

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running a [query job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets#defaultTableExpirationMs) on a large dataset in BigQuery. The job results are stored in a [destinationTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.destinationTable). I want the tables to expire either within *1 day* or *1 hour* (historical data va. today's data).
Is there an option to set **expirationTime** on each table?

I am aware that I can set a [defaultExpirationTime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets#defaultTableExpirationMs) on the entire dataset, but since I have different expiration times, this is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [expirationTime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#expirationTime) Table's Property

```
expirationTime  long    [Optional] The time when this table expires, in milliseconds since 
                        the epoch. If not present, the table will persist indefinitely. 
                        Expired tables will be deleted and their storage reclaimed.
```

You need to set it using [tables.patch](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/patch) API after table is created or updated (depends on your logic)

Comment: So I can't set it when creating the job, but I need to update the expirationTime on the newly created table?

Comment: Yeah, just noticed. Perfect.